# Freeze first 2 columns on Excel 2007

Tags: microsoft-excel

The excel 2007 cant freeze panes you selected. It only has options, freeze top and freeze first columns. 
How can i freeze the first 2 columns then?

Answer (score 2):

If you click in cell C1 and click on VIEW then go to FREEZE PANES and choose the first option that should freeze columns A & B.